# How can we digest protein, fats and carbs at the same time?

Tags: digestion, macronutrient

I read that carbohydrates need an alkakine environment to be digested while protein and fats need an acidic one, so how can the human stomach handle both at the same time ?

Comment: Where did you read that? A link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acidic environment *in the stomach* (ph ~2) is necessary for the activity of the enzyme pepsin, which partly digests proteins to peptides ([NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22600/)).

"Alkaline environment," which is not really alkaline but rather less acidic or nearly neutral with pH 6-7.4, ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10421978)) is *in the small intestine,* where carbohydrates, fats and peptides are digested.

Comment: So the "food combining" approach  (separating meals of mostly carbs from meals of mostly protein and fats) doesn't really make sense ?

Comment: No, from this perspective, I don't see any sense in it. Food combining approach is a known myth.

Comment: also the "don't drink anything with your meal because you will dilute your stomach acid" is also nonsense, while we're here.